# Batch to find highest version-string from amount of lines

Tags: batch-file

I need to determine what's the highest installed version of LocalDB within a batch script and set the whole version string into a variable.

`sqllocaldb versions` produces an out put like:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5058.0)
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
```

The order of the version string is not necessarily ascending. Need some help to set the highest server version into a variable (in this example 12.0.2000.8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to invoke the command and parse the returned string, with a combination of `FOR` command and `SET` command,

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('sqllocaldb versions') do (
  set verstr=%%a
  set verstr=!verstr:^(=!
  set verstr=!verstr:^)=!
```

then parse the version string into pieces with another `FOR` command, and compute a version number with a `SET /A` and simple arithmetic

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%b in ("!verstr!") do (
  set /a verval=%%b*1000000+%%c*1000+%%d
```

then compare it with a running max using  `IF GTR` command

```
if !verval! gtr !highval! (
  set /a highval=!verval!
  set highest=!verstr!
)
```

---

so, putting all the pieces together....

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a highval=0
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('sqllocaldb versions') do (
  set verstr=%%a
  set verstr=!verstr:^(=!
  set verstr=!verstr:^)=!
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%b in ("!verstr!") do (
    set /a verval=%%b*1000000+%%c*1000+%%d
    if !verval! gtr !highval! (
      set /a highval=!verval!
      set highest=!verstr!
    )
  )
)
echo !highest!
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** improved: no auxiliary batch script required. Next code snippet could work (note proper escaping applied to inner loop):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
echo show variables before
set _lastver

rem with an auxiliary batch script
>"%temp%\31110044.bat" ((for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%a in ('
  sqllocaldb versions
  ') do @echo @set "_lastverCall=%%b")|sort)
call "%temp%\31110044.bat"

rem using two nested 'for /F' loops: 
rem (note proper escaping applied to inner loop)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`
  ^(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%a in ^(^'
      sqllocaldb versions
      ^'^) do @echo %%b^)^|sort
`) do set "_lastverForF=%%x"

echo show variables after
set _lastver
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31110044.bat
show variables before
Environment variable _lastver not defined
show variables after
_lastverCall=12.0.2000.8
_lastverForF=12.0.2000.8

==>
```

Debugged with fictional values in `type "files\31110044.txt"` instead of `sqllocaldb versions`:

```
==>type "files\31110044.txt"
MiniSoft SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5058.0)
MiniSoft SQL Server 2014 ( 2.0.2000.4)
MiniSoft SQL Server 2013 (11.0.5046.0)
MiniSoft SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000.8)
MiniSoft SQL Server 2014 (11.0.4046.6)

==>
```